# Remote Get-ChildItem Return Value is wrong

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, get-childitem

I'm trying to list user profiles' sizes on remote computers combining **Invoke-Command** & **Get-ChildItem**, but there's an issue I can't figure out :

When I launch the command **locally** :

```
PS> (gci -recurse -force "C:\Users\user1" -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure -Property Length -Sum
).Sum
1038027666 # THE GOOD ONE
```

When I launch the command **locally with a RunAs** :

```
PS> (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force "C:\Users\user1" -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  | Measure -Property Length -Sum).Sum
68008251 # REAL SIZE IS WAY BIGGER
```

When I launch the command **remotely** :

```
PS> Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER1 -ScriptBlock { (gci -recurse -force "C:\Users\user1" -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure -Property Length -Sum).Sum }
7341685593 # REAL SIZE IS WAY SMALLER
```

If I get rid of **-ErrorAction** locally, in both situations I only get some Access Denied (For the good one, I have Access Denied on **Local Settings** and **Application Data**, surely that's why it's the good one)

If I get rid of **-ErrorAction** remotely, it seems that it tries to list **LocalSettings** and **Application Data** folders, that are not used with 2016 servers and that became **LINKS that are not even accessible** nowadays (how would it make SUCH a difference ?), and I get hundreds of these :

While these are exactly the same commands, the values returned are so far away from each other; I don't get it.

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user1\Local Settings\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application 
Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application 
Data\Microsoft\Windows\...'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\user1...:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : SERVER1
```

Could someone light me up on that behavior ? How could I get the good number remotely ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The short of it: During remoting, additional privileges become enabled that unexpectedly allow recursing into the hidden, for-backward-compatibility-only junctions such as `$HOME\Local Settings`. In PowerShell [Core] v6+, the problem no longer occurs, because these hidden junctions are no longer recursed into. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253342/45375) to the linked question for details.