# How to check for log4j vulnerability on windows (surface go)

Tags: windows, powershell, log4j

In this post:
https://gist.github.com/Neo23x0/e4c8b03ff8cdf1fa63b7d15db6e3860b
the following powershell command is claimed to check for log4j vulnerabilities:

`gci 'C:\' -rec -force -include *.jar -ea 0 | foreach {select-string "JndiLookup.class" $_} | select -exp Path`

That results in access denied errors.
Further checking reveals one has to run powershell as Administrator.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/32390/access-is-denied-while-i-am-running-a-command-in-p.html

Doing that still gives access denied errors.
Further on in the above article it says to first issue:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned`

That still gives Access Denied.

What is further required to get this to execute?

Comment: The access denied error mean that your current user doesn't have permissions to read the file, the ExecutionPolicy is unrelated to that.

Comment: `-ea 0` is short for `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, which normally suppresses error messages. Are you saying you're still getting them? Note that even when running _as admin_ there can be folders you're not allowed access to.

Comment: What you can do as of now is run the script you currently have, and get a list of those files that couldn't be read for later.

Comment: Note that there are system-defined junctions (links to other folders) that exist for backward compatibility only, whose content you're not permitted to enumerate even when running as admin - however, this isn't a problem, because they simply point to other folders whose enumeration _is_ permitted (only Windows PowerShell complains about these, PowerShell (Core) 7+ quietly skips them) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253342/45375).

Comment: As an aside: You can greatly speed up the command (which will still run for a long time) as follows: `gci C:\ -rec -force -filter *.jar -ea silentlycontinue | select-string "JndiLookup.class" | select -exp Path`

Comment: @mklement0 yes, I still get "Access is denied" errors. If I leave off the -ea 0, it says no access to path "C:\Doocuments and Settings", which seems strange.

Comment: The `C:\Documents and Settings` error is expected (in Windows PowerShell), as explained in answer I previously linked to. It's strange that you're still getting errors with `-ea 0` == `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, however. As an aside: You can collect them all by using `-ErrorVariable errs` and inspecting `$errs` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, it appears all of the complaints are about those hidden junctions.

Comment: There was a vulnerability in minecraft-launcher.  It was found by the script checkjindi.ps1, found here: https://github.com/CERTCC/CVE-2021-44228_scanner

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Use the following, streamlined version of the command, which should also perform much better.

```sh
# Run WITH ELEVATION (as admin):
gci C:\ -rec -file -force -filter *.jar -ev errs 2>$null | # Use -filter, not -include
  select-string "JndiLookup.class" |  # Pipe directly to select-string
    select -exp Path
```

Note: `-ea 0` - short for: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` - *should* normally silence any error messages, but if that doesn't work for you for some reason, `2>$null` should be effective.

`-ev errs` - short for: `-ErrorVariable errs` - **collects all errors that occur in variable `$errs`, which you can examine after the fact to determine whether the errors are an indication of an *actual* permission problem**.

**Errors *are* expected in *Windows PowerShell*, even when running with elevation, namely relating to hidden system junctions**, discussed below. However, you can *ignore* these errors.

In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where these errors no longer occur, you could omit `-ev errs 2>$null` above. Any errors that surface then would be indicative of a true permission problem.

---

**Background information:**

- In general, even running with elevation (as admin) doesn't guarantee that *all* directories can be accessed. File-system ACLs at the directory level can prevent even elevated processes from enumerating the directory's files and subdirectories.
- Notably, there are several *hidden system junctions* (links to other directories), defined for pre-Vista backward-compatibility only - such as `C:\Documents and Settings` and `C:\Users\<username>\My Documents` - that even elevated processes aren't permitted to enumerate the children of.

  - During file-system enumeration, this fact only becomes apparent in *Windows PowerShell*, which reports access-denied errors for these junctions. *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, by contrast, quietly skips them.
  - Even in Windows PowerShell the problem is only a *cosmetic* one, because these junctions merely point to directories that *can* be enumerated with elevation and therefore *are* with a `-Recursive` enumeration of the entire drive.
- To find all these hidden system junctions:

  ```sh
   # Run WITH ELEVATION (as admin):
   cmd /c dir c:\ /s /b ashdl
  ```

Additional information is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253342/45375).